# Delete the numbers command "uniq -c" created

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have used the `uniq -c` command, but now I don't have a need for that information.
How can I cut/delete that field?

I tried to read online about the cut command, but I simply didn't understand.

```
$ cat new-word-freq.txt | head -n20
     13
     66 1
     27 1805
     12 1806
     13 1807
     15 1809
     56 1812
     12 1813
     46 2
     26 3
     12 4
  10526 a
     25 abandon
     54 abandoned
     26 abandoning
     14 abandonment
     12 abashed
     19 abbé
    107 able
   1016 about
```

I simply want this output, without the first field from the left.

Comment: just don't use `-c`.

Comment: but i needed the -c. now i need to delete it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk '{print $2}' new-word-freq.txt
```

Comment: Note that it prints the second sequence of non-blank characters of each line in the input, which does more than removing the text added by `uniq -c`, if the original text contained blanks (would be OK for a list of words one per line as the name of the file and the OP's sample suggest though).

Answer (score 11):

If the output is as generated by GNU `uniq` at least, where the lines consist in a sequence of 0 or more space characters, a decimal number, a single space character and the content of the original line, then you can do:

```
sed 's/^ *[0-9]\{1,\} //' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following command :

```
cut -f 9-
```