# Extracting "count value" after using "uniq -c"

Tags: grep, pipe, cut, uniq

I'm playing with bash pipelines using a bunch of NBA data. I'm trying to count the frequency of players on the Cleveland Cavaliers, and right now my command looks something like `cut -d "," -f 2 nba2017-roster.csv | grep "CLE" | uniq -c`. The output is `15 "CLE"`.

I want the `15`, not the `"CLE"`. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking for is `wc -l`. `uniq` is an overkill.

Comment: @pfnuesel, or just `grep -c CLE` here and neither `uniq -c` nor `wc -l`.

Comment: @pfnuesel But that just gives me the number of lines, which is obviously 1 and not what I want?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UNIX, there's typically more than one way to do it.

Stéphane [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432124/extracting-count-value-after-using-uniq-c#comment779963_432124) the most straight-forward method, which is to *drop* the `uniq -c` in favor of just counting with grep:

```
... | grep -c CLE
```

If you really want to *keep* the `uniq -c` portion of the command-line, then you either need to find a way to remove the "CLE" or keep just the number. The [`uniq` utility is specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) to return counts in the format:

> ```
> "%d %s", <number of duplicates>, <line>
> ```

so one (of many) options to extract the `<number of duplicates>` would be:

```
.... | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}'
```

... which tells awk to split the line on whitespace then print the first field.

See [Delete the numbers command "uniq -c" created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/327052/117549) for the corollary to your question.